# How to know that Tomcat is running on windows or not?

Tags: tomcat

How can I check whether or not Tomcat is running on Windows? When I enter `http:\\localhost:8080` in a browser, it shows the welcome page. However, when I do `netstat` on `cmd` for port 8080, nothing shows. I haven't started Tomcat, so how was it automatically started? Is there any configuration which would cause Tomcat to auto starts on system restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following batch will do the search with `netstat`:

```
@echo off

netstat -na | find "LISTENING" | find /C /I ":8080" > NUL
if %errorlevel%==0 goto :yes

echo is not running
goto :end

:yes
echo is running

:end
```

Another possibility is to do a similar batch to search the tomcat executable on the system tasks using `tasklist`.

Comment: Thanks JosEdu. Above batch file shows message "is running". Now i shutdown it with command "shutdown" from cmd. But still when i type "http://localhost:8080/" in browser it display welcome page. But when i run your batch file it display "is not running". Why like that?

Comment: @Coder9606 The service executable process to Tomcat Web Server is tomcat.exe, you can check it doesnt exist in the task manager list. The reason because you see the welcome page is because your browser is using the local cache, if you clean the cache and tomcat is off you will not see anything on localhost.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution worked man. After clearing cache it is not showing welcome page . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `netstat` with no parameters then it shows only a subset of connections on the computer in question (e.g. `ESTABLISHED`, `TIME_WAIT`, `CLOSE_WAIT`, etc.).

You want to use the `-a` and `-b` parameters, as the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat) states, these parameters have the following behaviour:

> -a   : Displays all active TCP connections and the TCP and UDP ports on which the computer is listening.
>
> -b :             Displays the executable involved in creating each
>   connection or
>                   listening port. In some cases well-known executables host
>                   multiple independent components, and in these cases the
>                   sequence of components involved in creating the connection
>                   or listening port is displayed. In this case the executable
>                   name is in [] at the bottom, on top is the component it called,
>                   and so forth until TCP/IP was reached. Note that this option
>                   can be time-consuming and will fail unless you have sufficient
>                   permissions.

So if you use `netstat -ab` you will see *all* connections, including (hopefully) the Tomcat process that is bound to port 8080.

There are a few ways in which Tomcat could be automatically starting. It could be set to start automatically as a service (check `services.msc`), it could be in the Startup start menu group, there could be a toolbar utility that is starting it, or if you have an IDE like NetBeans running, the IDE itself could be launching it.

Comment: by netstat it didn't showed me Tomcat. How i can identify Tomcat from windows Task manager? I mean what is the Tomcat process name? My eclipse IDE is closed and in services.msc no Tomcat is mentioned but still this url http://localhost:8080/ is displaying welcome page

Comment: @Coder9606 - but what did the netstat output report the process listening on 8080 as?

Comment: Tomcat is not running thats why it is not showing in netstat, I was confused because browser showing me welcome page from Cache. Thanks for your support